# Is $f$ differentiable at $0$, where $f(x) = x$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

This is the function:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x& \text{if $x$ is rational}\\0 &\text{if $x$ is irrational}\end{cases}$$

My attempt:

It's easy to verify that $f$ is continuous at $x=0$ using the sequential definition of continuity. I claim that $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$. Assume the contrary and let $f'(0)=L$. Now, we pick an $\varepsilon$ such that $0<\varepsilon < |L|$. For this choice of $\varepsilon$ there is a $\delta >0$ such that if $0<|x-0|<\delta$ then we have $\left| \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} -L\right| < \varepsilon $. Now, pick $x' \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ with $0<|x'| <\delta$. Then we have $\left| \frac{f(x')-f(0)}{x'-0} -L\right| = |L| > \varepsilon$. A contradiction!

Is this proof correct?

Comment: The proof looks correct to me.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_continuous_function

Comment: @b00nheT. The $<$ in the last line should have been $>$ (a typo) so I fixed it. But the flaw is assuming $L\ne 0$. The proposer has only shown that if  $f'(0)=L$ exists then $L=0.$ But $f'(0$) does not exist

Comment: @DanielWainfleet You are indeed correct, thanks for pointing it out. My bad for missing it! I've added the correction in my answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $f(x)=\begin{cases}x&amp; \text{if $x$ is rational},\\0 &amp;\text{if $x$ is irrational}\end{cases}$ does not possess a derivative anywhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2781373/prove-that-fx-begincasesx-textif-x-is-rational-0-textif-x-is)

Comment: @nmasanta are questions seeking proof verification duplicate?

Comment: @Ashish K if you look at the answer given there, you can get your answer.

Comment: @nmasanta I was not looking for solutions. I was looking for an answer which asserts if my proof is correct or finds flaws in my argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT:** As @DanielWainfleet pointed out in the comments, your proof does not apply in the case $L=0$. The proof basically goes exactly like the one you have written: first you choose an $0<\varepsilon<1$ small enough, then you take $\delta$ as you please and look at the difference quotient for any $|x|<\delta$. If $f$ was differentiable, then it should hold that 
$$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\right|<\varepsilon$$
but by density of the irrationals, you can find an irrational $x$ such that $|x|<\delta$ and for that one
$$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\right|=\left|\frac{x-0}{x-0}\right|=1>\varepsilon$$
contradicting the assumption.

---

Another working approach is showing that approaching $0$ via irrationals and via rationals leads to different difference quotients:

Indeed :

- choose a sequence of irrational numbers ($a_n=\sqrt{2}/n$) tending to zero. Then $\frac{f(a_n)-0}{a_n-0}=0$ for all $n$
- choose a sequence of rational numbers ($a_n=1/n$) tending to zero. Then $\frac{f(a_n)-0}{a_n-0}=1$ for all $n$

Comment: The flaw in the proposer's proof is assuming that if $L$ exists then $L\ne 0.$ If $L=0$ then we cannot take any $\epsilon$ such that $0<\epsilon <|L|.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet You are indeed correct. My bad for missing it! I'll add the correction in my answer

Comment: Much of performance-magic depends on how easily we make or overlook unwarranted assumptions.